# Basic set theory question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As I understand it, Cantor defined two sets as having the same cardinality iff their members can be paired 1-to-1.  He applied this to infinite sets, so ostensibly the integers (Z) and the even integers (E) have the same cardinality because we can pair each element of Z with exactly one element of E.

For infinite sets, this definition seems problematic no matter which direction we come at it from:  We don't know up front that two infinite sets have the same cardinality, so we cannot conclude that their elements can be *exactly* paired.  And we do not know up front that two infinite sets' elements can be paired up exactly (because we don't know with certainty what happens beyond the finite cases we can verify).  So we cannot conclude that their cardinalities are the same.  The definition above therefore seems useless, since we cannot start from either side of the "iff".

It might be argued that if we state it as follows:  "For each element e of E, pair it with element e/2 of Z," then we have expressed the general case symbolically, and it works.  But we can only verify that for finite values of E and Z.  We can't know what happens beyond finite elements of those sets.  So expressing it symbolically does not seem to help.

Why is Cantor's definition not circular and therefore useless for deciding the question of infinite set cardinalities?

Comment: These questions aren't very intuitive in the infinite case. However, we must stick with the logic and formality here, to see how things come up: For your example, the only way we can prove for instance that $ \mathbb{Z}$ and  $\mathbb{E}$ has the same cardinality is by find either bijecitve function or both side injective functions. Here, the Id function on the even numbers is injective, while for the other direction, the function you suggested is injective as well. The way to prove it is the following: $ f :\mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{E} $ is injective since $f(x)=f(y)$ iff $2x=2y$ , $x=y$

Comment: We can prove many statements about infinite sets without having to verify infinitely many calculations. It doesn't take an infinite amount of mental effort to see intuitively that $f:x\mapsto2x$ is a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) between the integers and the even integers, and we can translate the intuition into a finite proof using the axioms of set theory.

Comment: Yes, intuitively, I can see that the above mapping is a bijection, and that we shouldn't have to try infinitely many cases. But how do we know that something is not changing "in the limit", "beyond the finite" or at some point where words will fail me?  (Maybe I'm on the road to becoming a strict finitist.)

Comment: "But we can only verify that for finite values of E and Z"  Why do you claim that?  We most certainly *can* verify it for infinite values.  For *any* of the infinite values $n\in \mathbb Z$ there is a unique $m = 2n$ in $\mathbb E$.  ANd for any of the infinite values of $w\in \mathbb E$ there is a unique $v=\frac w2$ in $\mathbb Z$.  So there is a 1-1 pairing for *all* of the infinite values.  Why do you think we can only do that for finite number of samples?

Comment: "But how do we know that something is not changing "in the limit", "beyond the finite" or at some point where words will fail me?" Definitions. $E$ is *defined* as the set of all values $2n$ where $n$ is a value in $\mathbb Z$.  So for *any* value of $w\in E$ there must exist some $n \in \mathbb Z$ where $w = 2n$.  And likewise for any of the infinite values of $n \in \mathbb Z$ there will be a $w = 2n\in \mathbb E$ by definition. I'm glossing over how we show that $n$ will be the *only* value for $w$ and $w$ will be the only value of $n$ but those are easy details to fill in.

Comment: There are a *lot* more details I'm brushing over.  How are the integers and the reals or any infinite set (which can't be defined by *listing* the elements) be defined in the first place come to mind.  But bear in mind one way or another they *are* defined. The Natural numbers, for instance, are defined by the inductive principal that every natural number has a unique successor. and inductively they follow from $0$ (and the integers come from the naturals by including the negative values).

Comment: Thanks.  It's becoming clearer.  This helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what the supposed problem is, but I can walk through some basic results to hopefully shed light on what's going on.

Two basic notions in set theory are sets and functions. I'll assume you agree that the notion of a set and the notion of a function make sense.

Consider a function $f : A \to B$.

$f$ is said to be injective iff for all $x, w \in A$, if $f(x) = f(w)$ then $x = w$.

$f$ is said to be surjective iff for all $b \in B$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

$f$ is said to be bijective iff $f$ is both surjective and injective.

We say that $A \preccurlyeq B$ if and only if there exists an injective function $f : A \to B$. We say $A \approx B$ if and only if there exists a bijective function $f : A \to B$.

Cantor's insight was that it is possible to assign each set $A$ something called a "cardinality". The cardinality of $A$ is denoted $|A|$. The assignment is done in such a way that for all sets $A$, $B$, we have $|A| = |B|$ if and only if $A \approx B$. The technical details of this are a bit complicated, but in the case that $A$ has exactly $n$ elements, $|A| = n$.

It turns out that once we define cardinality, we can also define the comparison operator $\leq$ on cardinalities. This operator is defined so that $|A| \leq |B|$ if and only if $A \preccurlyeq B$.

In practice, when one is first learning about cardinality, you should always take $|A| = |B|$ as a shorthand for $A \approx B$, and you should always take $|A| \leq |B|$ as a shorthand for $A \preccurlyeq B$.

We can prove explicitly that $\mathbb{Z}$ and $E$ have the same cardinality by considering the function $f : \mathbb{Z} \to E$ defined by $f(n) = 2n$.

To show that $f$ is a well-defined function, note that $E$ is defined to be $\{2n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Therefore, $f(n) \in E$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

To show that $f$ is injective, consider $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and suppose that $f(a) = f(b)$. Then $2a = 2b$. Dividing both sides by 2 gives $a = b$.

To show that $f$ is surjective, consider some $e \in E$. Then by the definition of $E$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $2n = e$. Then for this $n$, we have $f(n) = e$.

Therefore, $f : \mathbb{Z} \to E$ is a bijection. Thus, we have $\mathbb{Z} \approx E$. Using the notation of cardinalities, we have $|\mathbb{Z}| = |E|$.

There's nothing circular about any of it.

Comment: I think that helps.  StackExchange won't let me upvote things yet, but I would upvote this one if I could.  Thanks very much.

Comment: This would probably explain why my next question wasn't valid.  I was going ask this:  Let's assume that E has half as many members as Z.  I demonstrate this by linking each element of E with elements E and E-1 from Z.  This covers every element of both E and Z.  Because I can uniquely link one element of E with _2_ elements from Z, E must have half as many elements as Z.  Therefore, E and Z do not have the same number of elements.  But that is probably wrong because my proposed mapping is not a bijection, right?

Comment: @user3511585 The subtlety here is that we don't know what it means to have "half as many elements". One definition of "$A$ has half as many elements as $B$" is stating that $2 \times A \approx B$, where $2$ is some 2-element set. In this case, you can prove that "$\mathbb{Z}$ has half as many elements as $\mathbb{Z}$". This is not a contradiction.

Comment: yes, for a pair of finite sets, yes, that would be trivial.  I was still thinking about the integers and evens as infinite sets.  Intuitively (and incorrectly according to Cantor) the evens should have half as many elements as the integers.

Comment: @user3511585 Indeed. And they also have the same number of elements.

Comment: If you insist on defining "half as many" then yes, the evens *do* have half as many... but they also simultaneously have *the same amount*.  These two statements do not contradict one another in the infinite case.  You seem to be reaching for the notion of "relative density."  It may surprise you then that the relative density of the evens in the integers is indeed $\frac{1}{2}$... and that the relative density of the integers in the rationals is $0$... despite all three of these sets having the same cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching cardinality and infinity in the wrong way. For two finite sets $A$ and $B$ the sets are of the same size if and only if there exists a bijection between the two sets. This is somewhat obvious, and the proof is done in the first few weeks of any discrete math or set theory course.

Of course we cannot think about infinite sets in the exact same way, but we use the same idea of a bijection to identify "families" or "classes" of infinite sets, and oftentimes we say that these equivalent classes of infinities have the same size; although that is not entirely accurate it gets the point across that these infinities exist within the same group, and share attributes.

As someone commented there is a clear bijection between integers and even numbers, you can try find a bijection between integers and natural numbers, or natural numbers and fractions on your own time to indeed convince yourself that these infinities are in the same "family" as we defined above. We call this "family" of infinities Countably Infinite.

You may be wondering what the point of this is...if we are just mapping primes, to natural numbers, to fractions, to even numbers, etc. that doesn't give us any extra information or really say anything about the sets, that is until you realise there are infinite sets that cannot be bijected to the natural numbers, a classic example is the Real Numbers, this is proven in Cantor's Argument of Diagonalization (One of the most elegant mathematical arguments ever in my opinion.)

Answer (score 0):

There are many definitions where you kind of need to know the answer before you use the definition. I write "kind of" because **you don't need to have a proof for it, but you need to have a guess**. Then you write a proof to show that the guess is actually correct.

The definition of equal cardinality is such a definition. Another one that you might have seen is the definition of limit: $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta.$ Here you need to have a guess of the limit $L$ before you can show that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L.$ But primarily the definition is used to show some laws/rules. These laws can then be used to determine a limit and no explicit use of the definition is needed. Similarly one can find laws for cardinalities and use them instead of the definition.